# Dropdown not working with IFrame?

Tags: html, css, iframe

i use an iframe to load form. There is my i frame code:

```
<iframe 
   id='iframe'
   seamless 
   wmode="transparent" 
   height='1px' 
   src="http://test.com/iframe/iframeform" 
   frameborder="0" 
   scrolling="no" 
   id="iframe" 
   style='width:100%;height:900px;z-index:111'>
   </iframe>
```

This iframe is hiding a Dropdown menu.

I give a full `z-index` to my Dropdown but it is not helping.

The iframe hides my Dropdown.

Comment: need more code from `iframe` html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<iframe id='iframe'
   seamless 
   wmode="transparent" 
   height='1px' 
   src="http://test.com/iframe/iframeform" 
   frameborder="0" 
   scrolling="no" 
   id="iframe" 
   style="position: absolute; width: 500px; height: 100%; top: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 1000; border: 0;"></iframe>
```

Comment: not working dear Your css code is hide my i frame. Thank you.

Comment: I would rather suggest you to use Ajax. You can just embed the Ajax response to the particular div. Iframes are not a good practice and iframes always experience overflow problem. So better get rid of it.